# Delete layer from ArcMap using Python

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers

**Problem:**

- I'm trying to loop through all my layers looking for layer named `"CADAnnotation"`.
- If the layer exists then remove the layer from the mxd

**Notes:**

- Running from Stand-Alone script (ie. NOT within Arcmap)
- `"CADAnnotation"` Data Type is a CAD Annotation Feature Class
- `"CADAnnotation"` is NOT in a geodatabase, it's created from a AutoCAD .dwg
- `"CADAnnotation"` is within a Group Layer named `"ACAD"`
- If the group layer `"ACAD"` can be deleted that also removes `"CADAnnotation"` that would be great.

**Code thus far:**

```
for item in mxds:
    print (item)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(item)
    df=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Project Area")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*",df):
        if lyr.name == "CADAnnotation":
            print(lyr.dataSource)
            arcpy.Delete_management("CADAnnotation")
            print("Layer Deleted")
        else:
            pass
```

**Notes on Code:**

- I can find the layer no problem
- the line `arcpy.Delete_management("CADAnnotation")` does not work throws an error.

**Question:**

- How to I remove `"CADAnnotation"` and/or `"ACAD"` group layer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you want to actually delete the layer from the geodatabase or remove it from the mxd?

If you just want to remove the layer from your mxd, replace `arcpy.Delete_management("CADAnnotation")` with `arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)`

If you want to delete the data source you can do this.

```
for item in mxds:
   print (item)
   mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(item)
   df=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Project Area")[0]
   for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*",df):
      if lyr.name == "CADAnnotation":
         arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
         print(lyr.dataSource)
         arcpy.Delete_management(lyr.dataSource)
         print("Layer Deleted")
      else:
         pass
```