# Delete Turned Off (Unchecked) Layers from Arcmap with Python

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, layers

I have about 100 figures that have been updated countless times and a lot of the old data was left in each .mxd but was only turned off (unchecked) and not removed.  I would like to remove these layers from each .mxd but keep the actual shapefile/features in an achieve folder.

I have found a similar script that removes layers by layer name here:
[Delete layer from ArcMap using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29899/delete-layer-from-arcmap-using-python)

but it does not do exactly what I want it to do.

Does anyone have a script already written that does what I am trying to do?

Comment: If you don't wan to delete the layer from disk, just remove the "arcpy.Delete_management(lyr.dataSource)" from the script you linked to.

Comment: Sorry.  What i want to do is remove layers that are unchecked in the TOC.  The linked script removes layers by name.

Comment: Closely related to [How to turn off layers in ArcMap via arcpy?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73433/how-to-turn-off-layers-in-arcmap-via-arcpy)

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove only layers that are unchecked (not visible), you need to check the layer property "visible".  In this case you would just need to sub out:

`if lyr.name == "CADAnnotation":` for  `if lyr.visible == False:`

You should read more about layer properties at [Layer (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000) in the online help.